# Matlab - Multiline title of a suplots figure

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I'd like to achieve a figure with a few subplots and a main title at the top that looks as follows:

[image: Multiline title]

Code I use:

```
figure
suptitle({'Multi-','line','Title'});
subplot(7,2,1:4);
    % there's intentionnal gap between 2 plots
    % therefore subplots 5 and 6 aren't used
plot(X);
subplot(7,2,7:14);
plot(Y);
```

The problem is that the first line of the title goes beyond the figure.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[The documentation for `suptitle`](https://code.google.com/p/matlabtools/source/browse/trunk/graphics/suptitle.m?r=121) clearly states:

> Use this function after all subplot commands.

So your solution is:

```
figure
subplot(7,2,1:4);
    % there's intentionnal gap between 2 plots
    % therefore subplots 5 and 6 aren't used
plot(X);
subplot(7,2,7:14);
plot(Y);
suptitle({'Multi-','line','Title'});
```

Comment: Ok now it works but I had to change a fontsize in suptitle command. Regardless of that, is it possible to increase space between first plot and top margin?

Comment: Possibly, but `subplot` tends not to be very flexible - I would use subaxis (http://www.mathworks.co.uk/matlabcentral/fileexchange/3696-subaxis-subplot) if you need more flexibility.  In any case if I have answered your original question it would be nice to accept it ;)